# How do you set-up a flat file database?

Tags: database, graphics, computer-science, rdbms, flat-file

Let's say there's this database which is flat-file, stores all information in JSON Format

**https://github.com/Codetana/IkarusDB**

I download it, But I dont know how to set it up.. Like I'm finding my way around on how to mess with different types of database..

Can someone please assist me as to how do I set this up and show it's usage?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your background? Generally, you simply install any prerequisites, then follow the directions to install. You may also need to learn (at least at a basic level). Recommend you search youtube for how-to videos on the subject. You may also consider taking an online course on the database.

Comment: Computer Science is my background. However I figured this out, Thanks for all the help ! :)

Comment: That's good. Also, that was supposed to be "You may also need to learn (at least at a basic level) a programming language".